# Sails.js One to many association

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Using the example given on the Sails.js documentation page, I get the following error : "Maximum call stack size exceeded error".

```
items.find().populate("user", {name:givenName}).exec(function(err, response) {
  console.log(response);
}
```

The matter is that when I look with wireshark, the query on the database tries to find every user (and the database is big), but it doesn't make any join.

```
items
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| id        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | 
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
user
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| id        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | 
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |
| item_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
```

Comment: With this query you get all user in your database and populate items for one user,  is it what you want ?

Comment: I did a mistake, I just corrected what I wrote : I want all the items that have a user_id = user.id (both tables linked by primary/foreign keys)

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as:

```
items
    .find()
    .populate("user")
    .where({name: givenName}) //or .where({user: {name: givenName}})
    .exec(function(err, response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: I tried it, but it results that with wireshark, I get a "Unkown column items.name in field list"

Comment: I am guessing it's a typo problem, but I can't find where

Answer (score -1):

Ok, If like you said you want only items for a specific user do this :

```
user.findOneByName(givenName).exec(function(err, user) {
    items.find().where({user : user.id}).exec(function(err, response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I want all the items that have a user_id = user.id (both tables linked by primary/foreign keys) but the given parameter I have is for example a name. So with that name, I wanna get the id within the same table, and then join it with the other table.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with find/populate... You need to manually make your request with .query if you want to make a join but never use this. I think it will be bette to first retrieve your user by name and after make find/where

Comment: I updated my post to clear my logic, I could do it by using a SQL query, but  then I loose what the ORM should bring me, the fact that I could change my database one day and still be able to query it.

Comment: Yes but if you want a join you have no choice (as I know) but without join a edit my post to show you how